# How to change the overall font color and style in a project created in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to change the overall font color and style on a project I created in React.js.

In the App.css
I have tried writing the following

```
p {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto"
}
```

No change.

I am using Bootstrap(This may be unrelated, but I'm not sure).

Comment: please share the full code

Comment: Can't say for sure without looking over the code.                                                     If it's a specificity problem then try using the `!important` tag, eg. `color: white !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Some tags have their own color, so you can do something like this:

```
body {
  color: white;
} 
input {
  color: white;
}
textarea {
  color: white;
}
button {
  color: white;
}
```

And the color can/will be overwritten in the component scope.